# incorrect Rscript work when replacing medians

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have dataset

```
mydat=structure(list(code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "52382МСК", class = "factor"), item = c(11709L, 
11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 1170L, 1170L, 1170L, 1170L), sales = c(30L, 
10L, 20L, 15L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 15L), action = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("code", "item", "sales", "action"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

it has two groups by code and item

```
code    item
52382МСК    11709
52382МСК    1170
```

Also i have action column. It can have only two values zero(0) or one(1). I need to calculate the median by 1 preceding zeros category by action column, i.e. which go before one category of action column, and by 2 zeros by action column that go after the one category.
 if median is more than the sales, then do not replace it.

This solution good works if i have three preceding zeros category by action column, i.e. which go before one category of action column, and by three zeros by action column that go after the one category.
but if i have 1 preceding zeros category by action column, i.e. which go before one category of action column, and by 2 zeros by action column that go after the one category. it  doesn't work correct

```
replacements <- 
  data_frame(
    action1      = which(mydat$action == 1L),
    group        = rep(1:length(action1), each = 2, length.out = length(action1)),
    sales1       = mydat$sales[action1],
    sales_before = mydat$sales[action1 -1L],
    sales_after  = mydat$sales[action1 +2L]
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    med   = median(c(sales_before, sales_after)),
    output = pmin(sales1, med)
  )

mydat$output <- mydat$sales
mydat$output[replacements$action1] <- replacements$output
```

I get output

```
   code  item sales action output
1 52382МСК 11709    30      0     30
2 52382МСК 11709    10      1     10
3 52382МСК 11709    20      0     20
4 52382МСК 11709    15      0     15
5 52382МСК  1170     8      0      8
6 52382МСК  1170    10      1     10
7 52382МСК  1170     2      0      2
8 52382МСК  1170    15      0     15
```

but output should be

```
   code  item sales action output
1 52382МСК 11709    30      0     30
2 52382МСК 11709    10      1     10
3 52382МСК 11709    20      0     20
4 52382МСК 11709    15      0     15
5 52382МСК  1170     8      0      8
6 52382МСК  1170    10      1     **8**
7 52382МСК  1170     2      0      2
8 52382МСК  1170    15      0     15
```

how can i get correct output?

## edit

```
   code item sales action
1     a    b     2      0
2     a    b     4      0
3     a    b     3      0
4     a    b    10      1
5     a    b     4      1
6     a    b    10      0
7     a    b     6      0
8     a    b     6      0
9     c    d     2      0
10    c    d     4      0
11    c    d     3      0
12    c    d    10      1
13    c    d    10      0
14    c    d     6      0
15    c    d     6      0
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. Can you clarify the logic?

Comment: @Charlicito, this logic comes from this my post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876158/replace-median-for-category-by-condition-of-three-zero-before-and-three-after-se. In that post, i had to calculate  the median for three zeros category of action before  to one category , and three zeros after one cstegory of action. Now it is necessary to calculate the median by 1 zero category of action  before one  category and two zeros after one.

Comment: What do you mean by "three zeros category of action before to one category"

Comment: @Charlicito, i edited post. As you can see for group A+B by action column three zeros category then goes 1 category ,and then goes three zero category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has several severe flaws:

- it complete ignores the grouping by `code` and `item`
- it picks only *two* values for median calculation instead of the full range of zero action rows while the OP had requested to include 1 row before and 2 rows after each `action == 1`.

If I understand OP's requirements correctly,

- the OP wants to measure the effect of a sales action by calculating the median sales in a period around each sales action (excluding the sales during the action) and comparing it with the actual sales
- separately for each product identified by `code` and `item`.
- The length of each sales action can vary (streaks of `action == 1`)
- as well as the number of days before and after each action.
- The expected output is the sales figures on zero action days. On action days, this figure is to be replaced by the median sales of the surrounding zero action days *but only if* it is less than actual sales figure.

The function below takes three arguments, the dateframe and the number of zero days *before* and *after* a sales action. It returns a data.table with the `output` column appended as defined by the rules above.

```
sales_action <- function(DF, zeros_before, zeros_after) {
  library(data.table)
  library(magrittr)
  action_pattern <- 
    do.call(sprintf, 
            c(fmt = "%s1+(?=%s)", 
              stringr::str_dup("0", c(zeros_before, zeros_after)) %>% as.list()
            ))
  message("Action pattern used: ", action_pattern)
  setDT(DF)[, rn := .I]
  tmp <- DF[, paste(action, collapse = "") %>% 
              stringr::str_locate_all(action_pattern) %>% 
              as.data.table() %>% 
              lapply(function(x) rn[x]),
            by = .(code, item)][
              , end := end + zeros_after]
  DF[tmp, on = .(code, item, rn >= start, rn <= end), 
     med := as.double(median(sales[action == 0])), by = .EACHI][
       , output := as.double(sales)][action == 1, output := pmin(sales, med)][
         , c("rn", "med") := NULL][]
}
```

For `mydat` as given by the OP we get

```
sales_action(mydat, 1L, 2L)
```

> ```
> Action pattern used: 01+00
>        code  item sales action output
> 1: 52382MCK 11709    30      0     30
> 2: 52382MCK 11709    10      1     10
> 3: 52382MCK 11709    20      0     20
> 4: 52382MCK 11709    15      0     15
> 5: 52382MCK  1170     8      0      8
> 6: 52382MCK  1170    10      1      8
> 7: 52382MCK  1170     2      0      2
> 8: 52382MCK  1170    15      0     15
> ```

This is in line with OP's expected result.

As a second test case, I have modified the data from OP's edit to include a second action in a one of the groups:

```
sales_action(mydat2, 1L, 2L)
```

> ```
> Action pattern used: 01+00
>     code item sales action output
>  1:    a    b     2      0      2
>  2:    a    b     4      0      4
>  3:    a    b     3      0      3
>  4:    a    b    10      1      3
>  5:    a    b     4      1      3
>  6:    a    b     2      0      2
>  7:    a    b     4      0      4
>  8:    a    b     3      0      3
>  9:    a    b    10      1      6
> 10:    a    b     4      1      4
> 11:    a    b    10      0     10
> 12:    a    b     6      0      6
> 13:    a    b     6      0      6
> 14:    c    d     2      0      2
> 15:    c    d     4      0      4
> 16:    c    d     3      0      3
> 17:    c    d    10      1      6
> 18:    c    d    10      0     10
> 19:    c    d     6      0      6
> 20:    c    d     6      0      6
> ```

The sample includes two actions for the first product, both with a duration of 2 days and one action of 1 day duration for the second product.

For rows 4, 5 the median of the surrounding zero action rows, i.e, `median(c(3, 2, 4))` = 3, was taken.

For rows 9, 10, the median of c(3, 10, 6) is 6 which is less than the actual sales in row 9. So, only row 9 was replaced by the median value.

For row 17 the median of c(3, 10, 6) is 6 which replace the actual sales figure in `output`.

If called for 3 zero action days before and after we get

```
sales_action(mydat2, 3L, 3L)
```

> ```
> Action pattern used: 0001+(?=000)
>     code item sales action output
>  1:    a    b     2      0      2
>  2:    a    b     4      0      4
>  3:    a    b     3      0      3
>  4:    a    b    10      1      3
>  5:    a    b     4      1      3
>  6:    a    b     2      0      2
>  7:    a    b     4      0      4
>  8:    a    b     3      0      3
>  9:    a    b    10      1      5
> 10:    a    b     4      1      4
> 11:    a    b    10      0     10
> 12:    a    b     6      0      6
> 13:    a    b     6      0      6
> 14:    c    d     2      0      2
> 15:    c    d     4      0      4
> 16:    c    d     3      0      3
> 17:    c    d    10      1      5
> 18:    c    d    10      0     10
> 19:    c    d     6      0      6
> 20:    c    d     6      0      6
> ```

#### Explanation

The key point is to identify which rows belong to the period around each streak of action days. As `action` consists only of `0` and `1` we can use pattern matching in character strings with an regular expression.

For this, the `action` column is collapsed into a character string (separately for each `code`, `item` group). Then, `stringr::str_locate_all()` is used to find the start and end positions of the `action pattern`. `action pattern` is a regular expression that is looking for any sequence of `1`s surrounded by the required number of leading and trailing `0`s, resp.

In fact, the regular expression is somewhat more complicated as we have to use *lookahead* in order to capture overlapping action patterns such as `000111000` in `000111000111000`. The `end` position of the lookahead regex points to the last `1` in each sequence instead of the last `0`, so `end` will be adjusted later on.

Finally, the start and end positions are converted into row locations in `DF` rather than locations relativ to the group and are returned in `tmp`.

Now, we do a non-equi join which aggregates and updates `DF` with an additional `med` column which contains the median sales of the zero action rows which belong to each `start`, `end` range.

The remaining steps are to prepare the `output` column and to remove the helper columns.

#### Data

```
mydat2 <-
structure(list(code = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
    item = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
    "b", "b", "b", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"), sales = c(2L, 
    4L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I just want say.Perfect. Thnx.

Comment: could you help me with improving your script in this topic(if you not busy)? I don't know how to automatize it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312193/combining-scenario-to-replace-medians-by-groups-in-r  Thank you .

Comment: @D.Joe Thanks for pinging. Indeed, I am busy right now. Will have a look if time permits.